# Regex issue with PascalCase not hitting on the first word

Tags: node.js, regex

I am working on a function which should convert a string to PascalCase.  One of my test cases is still failing.  I think i know why but I'm at a lost as to how to fix it.

```
assert.equal(toPascalCase('  FOO bar baz'), 'FooBarBaz');  // works

assert.equal(toPascalCase('FOO bar baz'), 'FooBarBaz');    // fails
```

I think this is because the regex I am using is checking for a space first rather than also checking for start of the line.  I will not claim to be a regex expert so I'm hoping for some help here how do i get it to pascal case the first word.

```
/**
 * First letter of each word in a compound word is capitalized all others are lowercase.
 */
function toPascalCase(string) {

    if (isEmpty(string)) return '';

    return `${string}`
        .replace(new RegExp(/[-_]+/, 'g'), ' ')  // chars that are probably meant as space
        .replace(new RegExp(/[#$.]+/, 'g'), ' ') // invalid chars remove
        .replace(new RegExp(/[^\w\s]/, 'g'), '')   
        .replace(new RegExp(/\s+(.)(\w+)/, 'g'), ($1, $2, $3) => `${$2.toUpperCase() + $3.toLowerCase()}`)

        .replace(new RegExp(/\s/, 'g'), '')
        .replace(new RegExp(/\w/), s => s.toUpperCase());
}

function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}

module.exports = {
    toPascalCase,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp

```
new RegExp(/\s+(.)(\w+)/, 'g')
```

means "Match one or more spaces followed by a character..." when you probably want something like "match zero or more spaces followed by a character..."

"zero or more spaces" would be the regexp pattern `\s*`

Comment: Well that was a fast fix.  I have only been looking at this for thirty minutes.

Comment: Only 30 minutes? For a regexp? That's barely any time at all! Easy to slip-up with patterns sometimes - it helps to say out loud what a pattern is supposed to match.